# JetBrains IDE Support Extension - How to disable Chrome Warnings?

Tags: netbeans, intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

Hey there I've been using the JetBrains IDE support extension for a week now, and While it is great utility. I grow tired of clicking the "X' in the Chrome Yellow Warning ("JetBrains IDE Support" is debugging this tab.)

This may be a noobish question for experienced devs, but does anyone knows how to get rid of this Chrome pop-ups?

Thanks :)

Here is a snapshot:

[image]

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can disable this warning in `chrome://flags` using the **Enable Silent Debugging** flag:

[image: Enable Silent Debugging]

It's mentioned in the [comment #28](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=138258#c28).

Here is the direct link to the option:
`chrome://flags/#silent-debugger-extension-api` Just paste this to your Chrome addressbar.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! that worked perfectly... no more annoying yellow pop-up!

Comment: Chrome will need to be restarted for this change to take effect.

Comment: @RăzvanPanda every Chrome flag change requires a restart to take effect.

Comment: @CrazyCoder: I didn't knew that and was mentioning it to help someone who also didn't know.

Comment: @RăzvanPanda Chrome [displays a notice that you should restart it](http://img854.imageshack.us/img854/627/6hov.png).

Comment: @CrazyCoder: well it was pretty camouflaged there and I didn't notice it, they should display that message with a different color

Comment: The flag has been removed from the ui, but still works as a command line switch. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61317899/645296).

Answer (score 1):

For the ones who didn't understand ( like me :P )

You need to open this address **chrome://flags** in Google-Chrome and **Enable Silent Debugging**

Answer (score 1):

While the relevant flag has been removed from `chrome://flags`, you can still use the command line switch:

```
chrome --silent-debugger-extension-api
```

which can be persisted in your flags config (eg. `~/.config/chrome-flags.conf` on linux).

*See [Enable Silent Debugging is not available in Chrome browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59304414/enable-silent-debugging-is-not-available-in-chrome-browser)*

Answer (score 0):

For the newer versions of the Chrome this flag is not available anymore.

**So Here is the solution**

Open settings in your IDE then head into Tools>Web Browsers
then click on Chrome and hit the pencil icon and
write this in "command line options" finaly hit ok

```
--silent-debugger-extension-api
```

now close your chrome if it is open then try to launch it again using debug or run...