# Enable Silent Debugging is not available in Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome-flags

I am not able to see one of the Chrome browser flag - "Enable Silent Debugging" in latest updated Chrome browser. Please let me know if this flag has been changed to something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This flag got removed after version 79. You can still activate it using command option `chrome.exe --silent-debugger-extension-api`

Answer (score 2):

> chrome.exe --silent-debugger-extension-api

For macOS users,

> /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --silent-debugger-extension-api